# How do you delegate class methods?

Tags: ruby, delegation

I would like to make a class which delegates all instance and class methods to another class. My aim is to be able to give a class which is set in the app options a name which appears to fit in with the code around it.

This is what I have so far:

```
require 'delegate'

class Page < DelegateClass(PageAdapter)
  # Empty
end
```

However, this only seems to delegate instance methods, not class methods.

Comment: I think you should subclass `PageAdapter`

Comment: ShiningRay - I think you're right. I feel a bit stupid not thinking of that myself :) If you add it as an answer I'll select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want delegation, you want direct subclassing:

```
class Page < PageAdapter
  # Empty
end
```

Proof:

```
class Foo
  def self.cats?
    "YES"
  end
  def armadillos?
    "MAYBE"
  end
end

class Bar < Foo; end

p Bar.new.armadillos?
#=> "MAYBE"

p Bar.cats?
#=> "YES"
```

Comment: This was not the question :)

Comment: @metakungfu Note the comments: ShiningRay suggested subclassing, and the OP explicitly realized that was the correct answer. I added this answer because ShiningRay never returned and converted the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could define your own delegation scheme:

```
class Page < DelegateClass(PageAdapter)
  @@delegate_class=PageAdaptor
  def self.delegate_class_method(*names)
    names.each do |name| 
      define_method(name) do |*args|
        @@delegate_class.__send__(name, *args)
      end
    end
  end
  delegate_class_method @@delegate_class.singleton_methods
end
```